# Linq dynamic include

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Can some one please tell me how to dynamically include child object using linq.

```
using (var cont = _entities)
{
    var query = cont.ParentTable;
    if(includechild1)
        query.Include("Child1");
    if(includechild1)
        query.Include("Child2");
    return query.ToList();
}
```

The above code is not including child objects.But the below code does

```
_entities.ParentTable.Include("Child1").ToList();
```

Please some one suggest an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Set result of include to variable:

```
using (var cont = _entities)
{
    var query = cont.ParentTable;
    if(includechild1)
        query = query.Include("Child1");
    if(includechild1)
        query = query.Include("Child2");
    return query.ToList();
}
```